# Java - notify an outer thread from an inner thread

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am very new to multithreading. I'm currently working on a project which requires a thread to be started and upon completion notify the thread that started it and continue its execution.
I tried to use a boolean variable and instruct the system to print out some strings to indicate the stage of operation. Find the code below

```
public class BankDatabaseSQL {
private Connection connection;
private ResultSet resultSet;

private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/banktesting";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";

Account account;

public final Object monitor = new Object();

private PreparedStatement setBalance;
private PreparedStatement getAccount;
int numberOfRows;

/** code omitted **/

/**
   method in question
*/
public synchronized boolean authenticatePrint(){

    try{
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        do{
        ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        mainForm.accNo = account.getAccountNumber();
        threadExecutor.execute(mainForm);
        wait(); 
        }while(mainForm.verified = false); // while the verified variable of the mainForm object is set to false,
                                           // the thread should keep waiting. The process has not gotten into this
                                           // if statement. 
        if(mainForm.verified = true){

            System.out.println("time to notify");
            notify();
        }
```

The second method supposed to do the notifying is shown below

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
 public void run() {
        new MainForm();

}
public synchronized void onVerify() {
    VerificationForm form = new VerificationForm(this);
    form.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("\nTime to onVerify");
            if(form.verificationStatus = true){
                verified = true; // variable for the mainForm object to aid in notifying the thread
                System.out.println("\nVerified = true has been set!");

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code. Just to start with, how many `MainForm` objects do you create, and how many do you think it makes sense to create?

Comment: @SebastianRedl honestly, 2 mainForm objects are created when the code is run. I will deal with that later.

Comment: What GUI Toolkit are you using? Most of them have a dedicated GUI-Thread which should not be blocked (well - for long). Also, most GUI ToolKits have some kind of Dialog-Functionality ready to use with minimal configuration effort. You should look for this. As Sebastian said, there are many more issues here ...

Comment: Your terminology is a bit odd, "upon completion ... and continue."  Usually there is no "continue" after "completion."  "Completion" means you're done.

Comment: "outer thread ... inner thread"  Those words have no meaning in Java.  Threads are threads.  There is no "inner" or "outer", there is no "parent" or "child."  The only relationships between threads in a program that you write are the relationships that you define.

Comment: `extends JFrame implements Runnable` --- a truly awful idea.  Google for _single responsibility priniple_ (SRP).

Comment: `do{ ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` --- Creating a new thread pool each time around this loop probably is a big mistake.  A normal program only ever creates one or a very few thread pool(s) in its entire lifetime.

Comment: Thanks guys fro your answers. I was able to implement it in another way without multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `join()` in main thread, like below:

> mainThread.join()

it will wait until other threads finished, then main thread continue to execute.

But try to use other multithreading technology, like `CountDownLatch`,`Barrier` or `Cyclic`.